# Next and Back tabs in UIKeyboard

Tags: objective-c, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

using Xcode 4.3

I'm trying to toggle between text fields with a back and next tab in a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad keyboard. Can I add those to this type of keyboard? if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the entire keyboard (will need to make your own number buttons, etc.) with the `inputView` property on a text field.

Or, you can use the normal UIKit keyboard and add your own accessory view with your own buttons on top of the keyboard with the `inputAccessoryView` property.

See this example project: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009462-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Thanks, ended up inputAccessoryView added buttons looking good. Every time a create a button from code it's so much more versatile than the UIButton you drag from storyboard. Does anyone ever end up using those storyboard buttons in there final product?